# How to "upgrade" mutex ownership from shared to upgrade?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Sorry for my dumb question, but how can I
upgrade shared ownership to upgrade?

So what method is the opposite of the unlock_upgrade_and_lock_shared() one?
(Is there any.) 
So if an ownership is shared how can i "upgrade" it to upgrade without unlock_shared() and lock_upgrade()?

And I can not understand the concept of having upgrade ownership. 
Why isn't there method like unlock_shared_and_lock()?
So, what are the benefits of having ownership like "upgrade"?

Thanks ahead, and sorry for my English (and silly questions) :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your thread has upgrade ownership, or it has shared ownership, or it has exclusive ownership.  [lock_upgrade()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable.lock_upgrade) converts your ownership from `shared` to `upgrade`.  Upgrade ownership is provided so you have a direct way to obtain exclusive ownership without releasing the shared lock.

The [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable) here might prove instructive in understanding the lock ownership types, and how to manage all possible state changes.

Comment: So after and before lock_shared() and unlock_shared() can i call
lock_upgrade() and unlock_upgrade()?

Comment: The way I read it you can transition directly from no lock to either of shared/upgrade.  You can also transition from shared ownership to upgrade ownership, if the lock supports upgrade ownership.  You can then unlock completely, or unlock from upgrade to shared ownership (or exclusive, if you so desire). I think you would be better off posting sample code in a new question that shows the transition(s) you want to do.